# cordova webview flickering

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I have web-app build with php+mysql+html5+bootstrap. App is fully in https and all i want is make a cordova app that opens the webapps's url.
BUT also i need to implement in app purchase. That will come later on.
Currently the problem is that i reserved the sample main screen(index.html) for the in app purchase (perhaps not needed) and the app url wil open by using plugin

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(linkTarget, '_self',  location=no,zoom=no,hardwareback=no');
```

**It works, but whenever i click a textfield and the keyboard comes visible, i can see the index.html behind. How to hide it or load the https content into it ?**

Tested with old sgs 3 i9600, updated to the latest available android 4.3

series of photos shows what i mean. After clicking the textfield:
http://postimg.org/image/ka2covazh/